# How to change the label shown in static dropdown

Tags: php, html

I want to change a static dropdown for gender but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender" value="<?php echo $row['gender'];?>" >
    <option value="<?php echo $row['gender'];?>" >Select Gender</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

The value is printing in console but not in the UI where it is displaying as `SELECT GENDER`, though I need to display output with dropdown.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: btw, `<select>` does **NOT** have a "value".

Comment: No it is not displaying the value which is in database

Comment: please show your sql query you used

Comment: As i removed value between select then also it is not working As i need to display the data which is present in db

Comment: I'll ask you again: Define "not working". Not "showing" isn't much to go on.

Comment: SELECT * FROM registered

Comment: Note to all downvoted answers below. I can assure you it is **not** mine. I only upvote answers with a good explanation.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: yes you are right, agreed with u.. without explanation, answer deserve for downvote. :(

Comment: @devpro "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: i like fishing :p .... my brother @vard

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get selected value you need to add a 'selected' attribute to the option of select box. For that when you render options you must check if you $row['gender'] matches the option value and add word selected which means that option will be selected in your select box. If no option has selected attribute by default will be the first option in select box.

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option>Select Gender</option>
    <option value="male" <?php echo ($row['gender'] == 'male')?'selected':''?>>Male</option>
    <option value="female" <?php echo ($row['gender'] == 'female')?'selected':''?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

For example:

```
$row['gender'] = $male;
```

Html output will be:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option>Select Gender</option>
    <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
    <option value="female" >Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `IF/ELSE` condition.

Example

```
<option <?php if($row['gender'] == 'male') echo "selected";?> value="male">Male</option>
<option <?php if($row['gender'] == 'female') echo "selected";?> value="female">Female</option>
```

**Note**: Value of `$row['gender']` is supposed in above example.

You need to remove `value="<?php echo $row['gender'];?>"` from `<SELECT>`

Comment: This *ladies & gentlemen*, is why an answer gets upvoted. Because they gave a valid explanation and just didn't "drop" code with nothing to back it up with. ;-)

Comment: thank u hassan for editing my post... :) my vote for you @hassaan

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
<option value="" >Select Gender</option>
<option <?=($row['gender'] == 'male' ? 'selected=""' : '')?> value="male">Male</option>
<option <?=($row['gender'] == 'female' ? 'selected=""' : '')?> value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

**Explanation:**

No need to use `<select>` value, because it will return nothing. So remove `value="<?php echo $row['gender'];?>"` from select tag.

**How it works?**

As per your requirement, if database value `$row['gender']` is equal to "male" or female than select related option. For this you need to print `selected=""` in `<option>` as given in example.

Comment: at least leave your comments down voter... strange people, how can i improve this without your suggestion. be brave.

Answer (score -2):

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
      <option  <?php if($row['gender'] !== "Select Gender") echo "selected";?> >Select Gender</option>
      <option value="male" <?php if($row['gender'] == 'male') echo "selected";?> >Male</option>
      <option value="female" <?php if($row['gender'] == 'female') echo "selected";?> >Female</option>
     </select>
      <br/>
```